# Is it possible to pass a variable stored in an array by reference in PHP?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

If I want `myFunction` to take `$myVariable` and assign to it an instance of `SomeClass`, I know I can do this:

```
class SomeClass { }

function myFunction(&$myVariable) {
    $myVariable = new SomeClass();
}

myFunction($myVariable);

var_dump($myVariable);
```

However, I would like to be able to have `myFunction` operate like this:

```
class SomeClass { }

function myFunction($args = array()) {
    if(isset($args['something'])) {
        $$args['something'] = new SomeClass();
    }
}

myFunction(array(
    'something' => $myVariable
));

var_dump($myVariable);
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please stop making my head hurt.

Answer (score 0):

it's an ugly hack but could work:

```
 global $$args['something'];
 $$args['something'] = new SomeClass();
```

But you should never introduce such side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass variables by reference, so

```
myFunction(array())
```

will not work in either case.

Im not sure what your doing, but lets say

```
$myVariable = 'Mary';
$array['something'] = $myVariable;
```

Then

```
$$array['something'] === $Mary
```

Which doesnt exist.

I havent tested it, but I dont think that will work the way you want it to, even with global variables.